# JQTouch link with no animation

Tags: iphone, ajax, web-applications, jqtouch

Im building a web app using JQTouch and have been very impressed with it so far! I'm currently having a little problem in that I now need to link between certain parts of my site with NO ANIMATION. Reason for this is that I'm adding a 'tabbar' at the bottom of my page and in keeping with the whole iPhone feel would like to link to other sections with no animation. From what I've seen so far, the dissolve effect seems the closest I guess.

So just to clear up I dont want to disable all animations, only the four in my tabbar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add a custom animation which does nothing. See [this page](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/Animations).

So, if you want no animation you may want something like this (i.e. leaving out @webkit-keyframes):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        jQT.addAnimation({
            name: 'noanimate',
            selector: '.noanimate'
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .noanimate.in {
        -webkit-animation-name: dontmove;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .noanimate.out {
        -webkit-animation-name: noanimateout;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .noanimate.out.reverse {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-animation-name: dontmove;
    }

    .noanimate.in.reverse {
        z-index: 10;
        -webkit-animation-name: noanimatein;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Adding that makes any elements on the page untappable though